# How to filter a data set by date/time stamp to show only current date data?

Tags: filter, google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet

I am using new Google Sheet. The data set is this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LaZXonjnGoseGyrjiVurIaWvAmpVfPA3DiT8p8_KIoc/pubhtml.
(please note that in europe we use ; instead of , in Sheet)

Data comes from a Google Form input.

I need to be able to filter the data set to show only the **current date** data. Anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a FILTER() formula to only show the data from today. To do so, write the formula in a new blank sheet as follows:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER('Formularsvar 1'!$A$2:$Y;ROUNDDOWN('Formularsvar 1'!$A$2:$A,0)=TODAY()))
```

Hope that helps,

Mike